# Why does c# compiler allow incorrect match of return value type and variable type?

Tags: c#, dynamic, compiler-errors

Consider the following code:

```
static void Main()
{
    dynamic a = 1;
    int b = OneMethod(a);
}

private static string OneMethod(int number)
{
    return "";
}
```

Please notice that `type of b` and `return type of OneMethod` does not match. Nevertheless it builds and throws the exception at runtime. **My question is that why does the compiler let this? Or what is the philosophy behind this?**

The reason behind this may be `Compiler does not know which OneMethod would be called, because a is dynamic.` But why it cannot see that there is only one `OneMethod`. There will surely be an exception at runtime.

Comment: Read [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) (first sentence): _"The dynamic type enables the operations in which it occurs to **bypass compile-time type checking**. Instead, these operations are resolved at run time."_

Comment: @TimSchmelter thank you. In fact I did not search at MSDN. But my question was that what is the reason(or philosophy) behind this?

Comment: you have to ask E.Lippert, i guess he'd answer something like "if you use dynamic the compiler is no longer responsible to check the variable or any involved expression".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any expression that has an operand of type dynamic will have a type of dynamic itself.

Thus your expression `OneMethod(a)` returns an object that's typed dynamically

so the first part of your code is equivalent to

```
static void Main()
{
    dynamic a = 1;
    dynamic temp = OneMethod(a);
    int b = temp;
}
```

one way of argue why this is sensible even in your case depends on whether or not you think the compiler should change behavior for that particular line depending when you add the below method

```
private static T OneMethod<T>(T number)
```

Now the compiler won't know the type returned until runtime. It won't even know which method is called. The generic or the non generic. Wouldn't you be surprised if it in the first case marked the assignment as a compile error and then by adding a completely different method it got moved to a runtime error?

Comment: But what value could `a` have - that would change the return type of `OneMehtod` ?

Comment: @JensKloster see the edit. In general the compiler can't know what type is returned because that would mean it should pick the right method in the first place. However to do that you'd need to know the type of the argument which the compiler can't because you've asked it not to be interested (Ie by declaring the type as dynamic)

Comment: @RuneFS: do you have a source(documentation or C# specification) which confirms your first sentence?

Comment: Well I'd say it's section 7.2 of the specification. Though the above might be an over interpretation